# c# / .net textbox behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, textbox

Something I come across ever now and again which Im not sure why it happens

If I take a simple line of code in a buttons on-click event:

```
textbox1.Text = textbox2.Text;
```

when the button is clicked the text in textbox1 disappears and textbox2 is not updated.
Both textboxs have EnableViewState set to true.

If textbox1 is null when the page loads this happens, however if it has been populated from a database on the page load then textbox2 will take on the text in textbox1.

Cant seem to find a decent explanation online, can anyone comment?

Thankyou

Comment: How can `textbox2` be updated when you're assigning the text of `textbox2` to `textbox1`?

Comment: Well that code sets `textbox1.Text` equal to the text of `textbox2` which is empty. I assume you want it the other way around?

Comment: I suggest having a read of this to make sure you understand how assignment in C# works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 6):

Assignments go right to left. You are assigning the text from textbox2 to the text of textbox1. That is why textbox2 is not updated, and textbox1 is blank.

Comment: typo in the original question - I meant to put textbox2 = textbox1

Answer (score 0):

the page is loading again when I click the button, so if I put

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
```

within the page load and put all the other code such as the population of textboxes from the select then it works fine

thanks